# vim smart tabbing

Tags: vim, tabbing

In emacs, whenever tab is pressed, the cursor moves to the appropriate location on the current line. However, in vim, this does not happen, the tab is a given length and will go that far every time I press tab. Is there a way to enable "smart tabbing" in vim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what behavior you expect, but this is probably it.

```
:set smarttab
```

Also consider setting:

```
:set smartindent
:set autoindent
```

Comment: Also `:set cindent` which, per manual, works sometimes better but is more strict.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is the following. You have text like:

This is line 1

$ (lots of white space)    This is line 2

This is line 3

Now, you are in normal mode, your cursor is after $, and you would like it get just before T. If so, just press 'w' (to traverse a 'w'ord) and you would achieve your objective.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should clarify, in vim, when appending a file, whenever I hit tab, can it 'auto tab' where it should be? Like in an if/else block, after the bracket, in emacs, whenever I hit tab, it will tab over until I am under the bracket or lined up with the line under the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just want to use `==` to auto-indent the current line.